# GeoServer Failed to locate field false in class

Tags: geoserver, wps

I am trying to use the WFS/WMS in GeoServer (v 2.22.4) to create some dashboards in MapStore. While the error in MapStore hints at possible issues with the WPS and that the gs:aggregate might not be available, the geotools developer logging in GeoServer throws out the below.
My very limited experience and knowledge doesn't allow me to decipher it properly and I was wondering if anyone here could point me in the right direction.

I checked that the WPS, WFS and WMS are all available for the layer and workspace that I'm working on, and the declared CRS is 27700. Not sure if there are any other details that needed to be included.

There are 2 requests sent by MapStore:

1. http://localhost:443/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&typeName=workspace%3Alayer_name&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&request=DescribeFeatureType
2. https://localhost/geoserver/wps?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeProcess&IDENTIFIER=gs%3AAggregate

There is no response for the first request and the response for the second one is:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:ProcessDescriptions xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en" service="WPS" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd"><ProcessDescription wps:processVersion="1.0.0" statusSupported="true" storeSupported="true"><ows:Identifier>gs:Aggregate</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>Aggregate</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>Computes one or more aggregation functions on a feature attribute. Functions include Count, Average, Max, Median, Min, StdDev, and Sum.</ows:Abstract><DataInputs><Input maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"><ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>features</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>Input feature collection</ows:Abstract><ComplexData><Default><Format><MimeType>text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0</MimeType></Format></Default><Supported><Format><MimeType>text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.1</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>application/wfs-collection-1.0</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>application/wfs-collection-1.1</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>application/zip</MimeType><Encoding>base64</Encoding></Format><Format><MimeType>text/csv</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>application/json</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</MimeType></Format></Supported></ComplexData></Input><Input maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"><ows:Identifier>aggregationAttribute</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>aggregationAttribute</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>Attribute on which to perform aggregation</ows:Abstract><LiteralData><ows:AnyValue/></LiteralData></Input><Input maxOccurs="2147483647" minOccurs="0"><ows:Identifier>function</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>function</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>An aggregate function to compute. Functions include Count, Average, Max, Median, Min, StdDev, Sum and SumArea.</ows:Abstract><LiteralData><ows:AllowedValues><ows:Value>Count</ows:Value><ows:Value>Average</ows:Value><ows:Value>Max</ows:Value><ows:Value>Median</ows:Value><ows:Value>Min</ows:Value><ows:Value>StdDev</ows:Value><ows:Value>Sum</ows:Value><ows:Value>SumArea</ows:Value></ows:AllowedValues></LiteralData></Input><Input maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"><ows:Identifier>singlePass</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>singlePass</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>If True computes all aggregation values in a single pass (this will defeat DBMS-specific optimizations)</ows:Abstract><LiteralData><ows:DataType>xs:boolean</ows:DataType><ows:AnyValue/><DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue></LiteralData></Input><Input maxOccurs="2147483647" minOccurs="0"><ows:Identifier>groupByAttributes</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>groupByAttributes</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>List of group by attributes</ows:Abstract><LiteralData><ows:AnyValue/></LiteralData></Input></DataInputs><ProcessOutputs><Output><ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>result</ows:Title><ComplexOutput><Default><Format><MimeType>text/xml</MimeType></Format></Default><Supported><Format><MimeType>text/xml</MimeType></Format><Format><MimeType>application/json</MimeType></Format></Supported></ComplexOutput></Output></ProcessOutputs></ProcessDescription></wps:ProcessDescriptions>`

````
Request: getServiceInfo
25 Jan 15:05:45 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getCapabilities
    acceptVersions:
        version[0] = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:443/geoserver/
    service = WFS
25 Jan 15:05:48 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
25 Jan 15:05:48 INFO   [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: describeFeatureType
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:443/geoserver/
    typeName[0] = {workspace_name}layer_name
    outputFormat = application/json
25 Jan 15:05:48 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
25 Jan 15:05:48 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
25 Jan 15:05:48 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
25 Jan 15:05:48 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: describeLayer
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:443/geoserver/
    ExeptionFormat = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest = null
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@88f000b4]
    OutputFormat = application/json
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=DescribeLayer, OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, LAYERS=workspace:layer}
    Request = DescribeLayer
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.1.1
25 Jan 15:05:49 INFO   [geoserver.wps] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [process.factory] - Failed to locate the field false in class class org.geotools.process.vector.AggregateProcess
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [process.factory] - Failed to locate the field false in class class java.lang.Boolean
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
25 Jan 15:05:49 INFO   [geoserver.wps] - 
Request: describeProcess
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:443/geoserver/
    identifier[0]:
        value = gs:Aggregate
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
25 Jan 15:05:49 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.```
````

Comment: Please add the actual request and response and explain what exactly is not working

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for getting back to me. I'm not sure where to find the request that is sent from MapStore. It calls for a layer from our local GeoServer via the WFS and is relying on the WPS to be able to apply filtering and create a chart for example. It finds the layer successfully, but I can't progress with the creation of the chart as this error comes up: The server doesn't provide the needed services for the layer and the widget type selected

Possible causes are:

The selected layer is a raster layer
WFS service is not available
The WPS process gs:aggregate is not available

Comment: the request and response should be visible in the network tab of your browser debugger

Comment: Hi Ian. I've amended the post to include the request and response. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.